# Using moment object in for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I am trying to loop over a date range to create a bootstrap header row of dates. Following is my code:-

```
renderHeader(){
    var dates = [];
    const start = "2018-11-10";
    const end = "2018-11-24";
    console.log('Trying to enter the loop');
    for(let date = moment(start); date.isSame(end); date.add(1,'d')){
        console.log(date.format("Do MMM YYYY"));
        console.log(date.isSame(end));
        dates.push(<Col>{date.format("Do MMM YYYY")}</Col>);
    }
    dates.push(<Row>{dates}</Row>);
    //dates.push(<Row><Col>Dummy</Col></Row>);
    return dates;
}
```

For some reason the control doesn't enter the loop and I get a message on the Chrome browser saying

> Paused before potential out-of-memory crash

The browser console shows following output

[image]

If I remove the loop and enter some dummy data then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can use that as an iterator. Besides, it would be easier with a while loop.

```
var dates = [];
const start = moment("2018-11-10");
const end = moment("2018-11-24");

while(!start.isSame(end)) {
  dates.push(<Col>{start.format("Do MMM YYYY")}</Col>);
  start.add(1, 'day');
}

return dates;
```

Same principe as what you wanted to do. While is not the same date, push to the array and add a new day.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Coming from Java background, I didn't understand why the for loop didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

yBrodsky answered the main question but I just wanted to add that you also need to provide a *key* property to the  component to provide a unique id - this will get rid of the other warning you are seeing.  Probably could just use the date for this

```
while(!start.isSame(end)) {
   dates.push(<Col key={start.format("YYYY-MM-DD")}>{start.format("Do MMM YYYY")}</Col>);
   start.add(1, 'day');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are rendering a list of elements in a loop, you should add `key` prop to the element.

Change this line

```
dates.push(<Col>{date.format("Do MMM YYYY")}</Col>)
```

to

```
const formattedDate = date.format("Do MMM YYYY");
dates.push(<Col key={formattedDate}>{formattedDate}</Col>)
```